# What's the derivative of vector product to a matrix?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I am stuck by a question. $w$ is an $n \times 1$ vector, and is a column of this $n \times m$ matrix $\text{W}$, and $a$ is another $n\times 1$ vector. What is the derivative of $\langle w^T, a\rangle$ wrt $\text{W}$?

Comment: The derivative of what in relation to $W$?

Comment: sry man, updated

Comment: The position of the columns are determined inside the matrix $W$? Otherwise the question is ill-posed.

Comment: How about this column is denoted as w_j, the j-th column in the matrix W?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f = A:W$, where the colon denotes the Frobenius product.

To match the conditions of your problem, the first column of $A$ is the vector $a$, and all other columns are zero vectors.

The differential is $df = A:dW$, so the derivative is 
$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial W} = A$$